# Angularfire - Get email by uid? #askfirebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, angularfire

I have an Ionic application using Firebase so I opted to use Angularfire. Currently running Angularfire4. In my application I store the uid and I want to get email related with that uid. I use the email/password login provided by firebase. How can I translate the uid to an email?

The only [method found](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.auth.Auth) is when using nodejs.

Answer (score 1):

The only data that is exposed in the client-side Authentication SDKs is the profile of the currently authenticated user.

There is no way to look up user data for a UID with the Firebase Authentication client-side SDKs. While admittedly convenient, it would make leaking user-data way too easy.

The only way to [look up user data by UID is using the Admin SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#retrieve_user_data) that you found. The idea is that you run those in a trusted environment (e.g. a server you control, or Cloud Functions) and selectively expose the user data that your app needs.

Comment: Would it be ok to save the data locally and lookup a particular user email using the uid as a key? Obviously the password won't be stored in a firebase database.

Comment: I'd be careful exposing a list of email addresses to the client. But what is acceptable for your app is up to you. That is precisely why there is a server-side way to accomplish this.

Comment: I will try to use cloud functions first.